# Filter specific column in array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to filter a specific column in an array in php using the code below:

```
(strpos( 'meeting',$event['categories'] ) == false )
```

It is not working actually. An example of what [categories] hold is:

`$event['categories'] = 'meeting;skype'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the array? A `print_r` would be great.

Comment: `strpos` can return `false` but also `0` which when cast to boolean is `false`. You need to test against types too, so use `===` or `!==`.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps it's not a problem of the array because it does access all other columns correctly.

Comment: use `(strpos( 'meeting',$event['categories'] ) !== false )`

Comment: @JYoThI or in my case (strpos( 'meeting',$event['categories'] ) === false ) right?

Comment: yeah that's also right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flip the arguments to `strpos()`:

```
if (strpos($event['categories'],  'meeting') === false) {
    echo $event['categories'] . ' does not contain "meeting"';
}
```

Also, use strict comparison (`===` vs `==`), as `meeting` could be at the start of the string, and then `strpos()` would return `0`, which would evaluate to `false` (which would be wrong in that case).

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/Ab4ud

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `===` not `==` and also flip the arguments

```
(strpos($event['categories'] , 'meeting') === false )
```

strpos could return `0` or `false` and when you use `==` then zero is like false

see [compression operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison)

see [`strpos()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: This is half good, but the arguments still need to be flipped!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$event = ['categories' => 'meeting;skype'];
$needle = 'meeting';
$haystack = $event['categories'];
if( ($pos = strpos( $haystack, $needle )) === false){
   echo "\n$needle not found in $haystack";
} 
else
{
     echo "\n$needle exists at position $pos in $haystack";
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/kKTJe)

The two things to watch out for are the order of the parameters for [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) as well as doing a strict comparison using the identity operator ("===") so that when the 'needle' appears at position zero of the 'haystack' it's not mistakenly deemed a false result which occurs if you use the equality operator ("=="), given that in PHP zero == false.